# How to print from a list?

Tags: python, list, operating-system

I just started to learn python and system programming.  For a homework assignment, I need to find and print the nth prime number.  I wrote the code below - I can find a list of prime numbers that are less than or equal to n, however, I don't know how I can print the nth prime from the list I created.  I keep getting the index error: list index out of range.

I believe I'm missing something.  Can someone take a look at my code and give me some guidance on how to fix it?  Your help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

```
import sys
import math


def s_prime(n):
    is_prime=list(range(n+1))
    for i in range(2, int(n**0.5)+1):
        if is_prime[i]:
            for j in range(i**2,n+1,i):
                is_prime[j]=False
    print 'Prime Value in Decimal: ', [x for x in is_prime[2:] if x]
    x_list = [x for x in is_prime[2:] if x]
    print x_list[n-1] 


def main(argv):
    input = int(sys.argv[1])
    if input == 1:
        print 2
    elif input == 2:
        print 3
    else:
        n = int(round(input*(math.log(input,2))))
        s_prime(n)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: If you're just starting out with Python, I would recommend using Python 3.x, unless your class requires Python 2.x. (Your print statements are not functions here.) Also, with index errors, I highly recommend printing out the indices first and the length of whatever list you're using as a debugging step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you changed the value of n here, `n = int(round(input*(math.log(input,2))))`. It is now something bigger than the original `n`. For example when `input = 5`, `n` is 12 and clearly the `x_list` contains only `5` items so you're going to get `IndexError` as index 11 is out of bound.

You can either using negative indexing here:

`return x_list[-1]` to get the last element.

or pass the original `input` to the prime function:

```
def s_prime(n, inp):
    print n
    #you code here....
    print x_list[inp-1] 

def main(argv):
     #your code
        n = int(round(input*(math.log(input,2))))
        s_prime(n, input) #pass input here
```

Comment: I used your suggestion and modified my functions.  It worked! Thank you so much! =)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you generate primes up to n and store them in a list.  Clearly, this list has fewer than `n` items, so when you try to find the `nth` prime, you get the `"index out of range error"`.

To fix this, you can generate primes as you go until you find the `nth` prime, or you can pick a larger upper bound for generating your list of primes.  You can use this to help you pick [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number) upper bound.